# How to pass data from Dexie to Vue synchronously?

Tags: indexeddb, vuejs2, vue.js, dexie

The fact is that I'm using Dexie + VueJs, and I'm printing a table with the list of the records, and one additional field for counting dependent records, however, I don't get how to do it in a neat way.

What I'd like to do is:

```
var vueElement = new Vue({
el: '#myElement',
data: {
    states: []
},
computed: {
    cities: function (s) {
        return db.cities.where('stateId').equals(s.id).count(); // How can I do this?
    }
}
});
// Initialize states in vue object
db.states.toArray().then(function (arr) {
    vueElement.states = arr;
});
```

Comment: Sorry not familiar with dexie, does the `db.cities...` return a promise?

Comment: try using `methods` instead of `computed` property.

Comment: @Austio Yes, it returns a Promise.

Answer (score 2):

Because most if not all dexie operations are running async you need to FIRST do dexie async operations and THEN (initialize vue component with the data returned by dexie).

Or you can try to initialize the vue component with no data and in on created/on mounted depending on your use case, request data from db and update your state.

I hope it helps

Comment: The problem with this approach is that Vue template will not render the updates coming from Dexie